# FFT for giga samples and longer

Tags: fft

I have a task that involves computing 1D FFTs of very large dimension. And, by "very large", I mean dimensions that exceed the amount of my physical memory. For example, I have 16 GB of memory in my system right now, which would be enough to keep 2^30 double-precision floats simultaneously. I want to be able to do a FFT of dimension of 2^30, and possibly a FFT on an even larger number of floats (say, 2^35), which would obviously require passing them in to the FFT library piece by piece.

According to my tests, IPP FFT won't go above 2^27 and NVIDIA CUFFT won't go above 2^24. I've been able to cook up some code to do this but I'm not happy with the performance.

Is there an open source project or a library that would do this for me?

Comment: The search term you need for this is "Out-of-core FFT" - see e.g. Cormen and Nicol: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/papers/PER.ps.gz

Answer (score 2):

Out-of-core FFTs will be limited by available disk bandwidth, and then disk seek latency if not striped optimally.  You might consider putting a couple fast SSD drives on your system, or instead renting time on a server (in the "cloud") which has enough physical RAM (and possibly also CPUs with huge dcaches, maybe Itanium or Power 7) to do your FFT in-core.